# Stopping a view from unloading its data

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

This may sound like a simple question, but yet I can't find an answer for it anywhere.

I am switching between views and everything is fine. I can pass variables and data between views, but the problem arises when I want to go back to a previous view.

Any data on the view is gone and deleted as if it hadn't been passed through. Of course, I don't want the data to unload when I switch to a new view. Is this possible?

This is how I am switching between views in my project. Is there a better way?

```
TicketStart *backPage=[[TicketStart alloc]initWithNibName:@"TicketStart" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:backPage];
[self.view addSubview:backPage.view];
```

When I search this question all I can find are questions about passing things through or loading new views. Sorry if this question has been asked, but I can not find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Do you have one view controller for both views?  If so, set a strong reference to both and don't re-initialize/allocate them after the initial time.

Comment: You are initializing a new view, which is why it's blank.  (It's a different view of the same class.)  You need to hang on to the first view you made, either in an instance variable, or a property.

Comment: @JeffCompton I have two separate view controllers

Comment: @AaronBrager How would I hang on to it in the ways you describe?

Comment: You'll need a parent view controller for the two you have.  The parent view controller should have a strong reference to the two view controllers and the view controllers should have a strong reference to the views.

Comment: If you are using storyboard, why don't you just use segue? and to go back to the previous controller  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; every time you use this line TicketStart *backPage=[[TicketStart alloc]initWithNibName:@"TicketStart" bundle:nil]; you are initializing the controller and all the content.

Comment: What do you mean by "go back to a previous view" -- which view are you talking about? TicketStart? Why are you switching to backPage by adding it as a child of your other controller (whatever self is) rather than using a push or presentViewController?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what triggers your views to change, so you'll have to write that code.

Parent

```
@implementation ParentViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.vcOne = [[OneViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:self.vcOne];
    [self.view addSubView:self.vcOne.view];
    self.vcTwo = [[TwoViewController alloc] init];
}

-(void)switchViews {
    //logic to animate in view that isn't present
}
@end
```

View Controller One

```
@interface OneViewController ()
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIView *vOne;
@end

@implementation OneViewController
-(UIView*)vOne {
    if(_vOne == nil) {
        _vOne = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    }
    return _vOne;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.view addSubView:self.vOne];
}
@end
```

View Controller Two

```
@interface TwoViewController ()
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIView *vTwo;
@end
@implementation TwoViewController
-(UIView*)vTwo {
    if(_vTwo == nil) {
        _vTwo = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    }
    return _vTwo;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.view addSubView:self.vTwo];
}
@end
```